A pre-Ramsey set that is not Ramsey
$\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}$
Recall that given a $A \in [\N]^\omega$ and $a \in [A]^{<\omega}$, the Ellentuck neighbourhood is defined to be:
$$
[a,A] := \{B \in [\N]^\omega : a \sqsubseteq B \subseteq A\}
$$
where $a \sqsubseteq B$ means that $a$ is an initial segment of $B$. A set $X \subseteq [\N]^\omega$ is (completely) Ramsey if for all $A \in [\N]^\omega$ and $a \in [A]^{<\omega}$, there exists some $B \in [a,A]$ such that $[a,B] \subseteq X$ or $[a,B] \subseteq X^c$.
Fix some $A \in [\N]^\omega$ and $a \in [A]^{<\omega}$. We consider the following infinite game we call $G[a,A]$:

Player I chooses some $N_0 \geq 0$.
Player II responds with some $x_0 \in A$ such that $x_0 > \max(a)$ and $x_0 \geq N_0$.
Player I chooses some $N_1 \geq 0$.
Player II responds with some $x_1 \in A$ such that $x_1 > x_0$ and $x_1 \geq N_1$.
Etc.

Player I wins iff $a \cup \{x_0,x_1,\dots\} \in X$. Let's call a subset $X \subseteq [\N]^\omega$ pre-Ramsey if for all $A \in [\N]^\omega$ and $a \in [A]^{<\omega}$, there exists some $B \in [a,A]$ such that the game $G[a,B]$ is determined. It's clear that every Ramsey set is pre-Ramsey.
I would like to know if the converse is true. A simple positive answer is unlikely, as that would give a positive answer to the long-standing open problem of if the axiom of determinacy implies that all sets are Ramsey. Is it provable in $\mathsf{ZFC}$, or at least consistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$, that there exists a pre-Ramsey set that is not Ramsey?
